# SAML identity provider interoperability with remote Active Directory domain

Tags: authentication, active-directory, saas, saml-2.0

We have a SaaS system based on SAML 2.0 authentication using an Identity Provider and we want to provide several ways of logging in, Form Authentication, Facebook, etc. Is it possible to connect the SAML system to a remote application using Active-Directory, ideally to gain access to the API also but most importantly to be able to use their authentication with the remote active directory as a means of logging in to the SaaS system?

Comment: Can you clarify/simplify your question? I'm not entirely sure what it is you 1) have in place and 2) what you are trying to do. All I can deduce is that your company makes a SaaS App and that you act as a SAML2 Service Provider currently. Thx - Ian

Comment: We are attempting provide various ways for companies to move their applications to a cloud environment and provides multitenancy self service signup,federated authentication SAML 2.0. We want to single sign on service that currently works with salesforce, basic forms andd facebook, as a .NET system we wish to use AD as a  means of logging in also

Answer (score 0):

Check out PingFederate and PingOne from Ping Identity (note: I work for Ping).  We have complete IDP **and** SP support (SAML1.1, 2.0, WS-Fed (Passive)) as well as support for LDAP, SFDC, OpenID and other Cloud Identity providers (LinkedIn, Facebook, etc). We also have support for Web Services security via Oauth2 and WS-Trust.